# how can I make offline browser for iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, offline-browsing

I need to make an offline browser on my iOS application, which allows the following:

When you have an internet connection (wifi, 3g, 4g, ...) you can download all the web pages you need to read during the day, then you can browse the content also when you have no internet connection.
I import the data from JSON file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data downloaded, save it to the documents directory and check if no internet connection, then load the content from the documents directory.

Get Documentpath

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you have an NSDictionary:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[dict writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myOfflineData"] atomically:NO];
```

And to get it:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myOfflineData"]];
```

Or save it with a NSString etc.

To catch up your Example:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:......."]];
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; jsonResults = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"nodes"];
[jsonData writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myOfflineData"] atomically:NO];
```

And if you are offline:

```
NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myOfflineData"]];
```

Comment: let me try it, then i will give you a feedback

Comment: look, where should I include this code?, the code that I get the data is: `NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:......."]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    jsonResults = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"nodes"];` which jsonresults is a mutable array

Comment: just save the nsdata to your documents and load it when you are offline. just replace nsdictionary with nsdata

Comment: I will test it, then I will tell you if it will work thank you

Comment: Can you tell me in which method I will implement it, in fact, in the root view I implement the code above, in the appdelegate I implement an alert to the user to tell that No connection. The storage of data and to get it where should I implement it?

Comment: You could just implement it in your rootView and use the Reachability class from Apple to check if there is no connection or not, this logic should not be placed in the appDelegate though. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/